# Bash script using expect and interact

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, expect

I'm trying to create a simple script to log into a device run a command and grep the output for a word.

so far I have

```
!/bin/bash
echo ""
echo -n "Number: "
read number
echo ""

if [ "$number" = "1" ]; then

/usr/bin/expect <<EOC
set timeout 20
spawn telnet 1.1.1.1

expect "Password"
send "admin\r"
expect "Command->"
send "Status\r"
expect "Commmand->"
send "exit\r"

EOC
fi
```

when I run the script the following is output

```
Number: 1

spawn telnet 1.1.1.1
Trying 1.1.1.1...
Connected to 1.1.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Telnet command shell
Please input username and password!
Command->admin
Username and password is ok!
Type 'help' and return for help
Command->Status
Port Status:
Port1=Yes
Port2=No
Port3=Yes
Port4=No
```

What i'd like to be able to do is for the telnet session to run in the background and only return the value of 'Number' ie

```
Number: 1
Yes
```

Comment: I'd recommend starting with `autoexpect`: you run the entire session interactively and it's recorded as an expect script.

Comment: This can be done with standalone `expect` script itself. Clarify one thing. After executing status command, what is the output value we are expecting ?

Comment: 1=Yes
    2=No
    3=No
    4=Yes

Comment: So, if you are running this "by hand", after you type the Status command, what do you need to do to exit?

Comment: type exit but i tried adding send "exit\r" to thte script but it didn't work.

Comment: I've fixed the exit problem it was due to not having expect "Command->" after running 'Status'. I now need a way to grep 'Status'

Comment: Up dated the original question.

Comment: Still don't quite understand your requirements. Could you give an example as if you're manually interacting with the system?

Comment: updated original question, hopefully it's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I just sent all output to a file and then greped out the required information.